# Libgdx contact fixture

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I'm trying to implement Box2d's [ContactListener](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/ContactListener.html) interface. The method called when a contact happens receives a [Contact](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/physics/box2d/Contact.html) object. This object then provides `getFixtureA` and `getFixtureB` getters.

Is there a rule, that says which fixture is assigned to A and which to B or do I have to check all combinations, as in:

I have bodies X, Y, Z and want to check if X and Y collided. Do I have to always check if `(A == X && B == Y) || (A == Y && B == X)` or is one of the two sufficient?

(A is contact.getFixtureA(); and B is contact.getFixtureB();)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to check both possibilities, Box2D [provides no specific ordering](http://www.box2d.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=5833).

As irresistable force says, there would be no logical ordering for fixtures in a contact:

> If they were ordered somehow, how would they be ordered?